# Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, android-emulator, android-logcat

I am developing guess the celebrity app and facing the problem that my apps takes 7-10 minutes to process on my device and emulator. I don't have errors and my emulator and device screen remains blank till the time my app completes processing(7-10 minutes).What should I do?

Logcat shows the following :

```
07-26 19:27:25.574 10637-10637/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)

07-26 19:27:25.574 10637-10637/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86

07-26 19:27:25.713 10637-10637/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Starting a blocking GC Explicit

07-26 19:27:25.756 10637-10637/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8368(373KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 4MB/6MB, paused 5.427ms total 37.235ms

07-26 19:27:25.966 10637-10663/com.personal.guessthecelebrity V/StudioProfiler: Acquiring Application for Events

07-26 19:27:26.064 10637-10637/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

07-26 19:27:26.179 10637-10666/com.personal.guessthecelebrity D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

07-26 19:27:29.931 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 360(11KB) AllocSpace objects, 354(6MB) LOS objects, 24% free, 12MB/16MB, paused 1.154ms total 104.832ms

07-26 19:27:32.830 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.605ms

07-26 19:27:32.840 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 311(9KB) AllocSpace objects, 306(10MB) LOS objects, 32% free, 5MB/7MB, paused 6.746ms total 35.416ms

07-26 19:27:35.783 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.504ms

07-26 19:27:35.803 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 192(5KB) AllocSpace objects, 185(9MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 4MB/7MB, paused 7.211ms total 43.629ms

07-26 19:27:36.024 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.319ms

07-26 19:27:36.035 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 105(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 101(5MB) LOS objects, 45% free, 4MB/8MB, paused 8.508ms total 23.726ms

07-26 19:27:37.303 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.793ms

07-26 19:27:37.309 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 79(2464B) AllocSpace objects, 76(4MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 8.401ms total 40.358ms

07-26 19:27:38.048 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.910ms

07-26 19:27:38.076 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 91(2848B) AllocSpace objects, 86(5MB) LOS objects, 25% free, 11MB/15MB, paused 7.154ms total 52.801ms

07-26 19:27:41.586 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.116ms

07-26 19:27:41.591 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 58(1808B) AllocSpace objects, 53(3MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 4MB/7MB, paused 8.868ms total 21.070ms

07-26 19:27:43.075 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.735ms

07-26 19:27:43.095 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 103(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 99(7MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 4MB/7MB, paused 7.023ms total 36.237ms

07-26 19:27:43.141 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.744ms

07-26 19:27:43.152 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 60(1952B) AllocSpace objects, 59(4MB) LOS objects, 25% free, 5MB/7MB, paused 7.711ms total 34.570ms

07-26 19:27:43.591 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.090ms

07-26 19:27:43.609 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 184(5KB) AllocSpace objects, 179(14MB) LOS objects, 34% free, 7MB/11MB, paused 7.368ms total 50.283ms

07-26 19:27:44.076 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 70(2240B) AllocSpace objects, 69(5MB) LOS objects, 44% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 5.594ms total 21.429ms

07-26 19:27:45.830 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 119(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 116(10MB) LOS objects, 44% free, 4MB/8MB, paused 6.166ms total 29.151ms

07-26 19:27:46.095 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.443ms

07-26 19:27:46.124 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 159(5KB) AllocSpace objects, 154(13MB) LOS objects, 41% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 8.577ms total 58.034ms

07-26 19:27:47.866 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.826ms

07-26 19:27:47.876 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 51(1568B) AllocSpace objects, 47(4MB) LOS objects, 38% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 13.280ms total 30.625ms

07-26 19:27:48.159 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 62(1936B) AllocSpace objects, 58(5MB) LOS objects, 40% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 5.436ms total 41.677ms

07-26 19:27:48.350 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 165(5KB) AllocSpace objects, 164(16MB) LOS objects, 17% free, 9MB/11MB, paused 11.099ms total 31.386ms

07-26 19:27:48.884 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.244ms

07-26 19:27:48.890 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 155(4KB) AllocSpace objects, 147(14MB) LOS objects, 40% free, 4MB/8MB, paused 10.560ms total 32.987ms

07-26 19:27:50.405 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.650ms

07-26 19:27:50.411 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 120(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 117(12MB) LOS objects, 40% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 8.911ms total 24.828ms

07-26 19:27:51.361 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.716ms

07-26 19:27:51.368 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 28(928B) AllocSpace objects, 25(2MB) LOS objects, 29% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 8.656ms total 25.378ms

07-26 19:27:51.634 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.502ms

07-26 19:27:51.663 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 99(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 95(10MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 4MB/8MB, paused 10.757ms total 66.548ms

07-26 19:27:54.906 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.427ms

07-26 19:27:54.924 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 109(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 107(12MB) LOS objects, 34% free, 7MB/11MB, paused 9.883ms total 31.305ms

07-26 19:27:55.176 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.520ms

07-26 19:27:55.188 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 29(944B) AllocSpace objects, 26(3MB) LOS objects, 33% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 9.721ms total 30.084ms

07-26 19:27:55.381 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 135(4KB) AllocSpace objects, 131(15MB) LOS objects, 41% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 10.562ms total 25.634ms

07-26 19:27:56.915 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.728ms

07-26 19:27:56.930 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 40(1232B) AllocSpace objects, 34(4MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 10.865ms total 35.755ms

07-26 19:27:57.641 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 202(6KB) AllocSpace objects, 199(24MB) LOS objects, 40% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 5.295ms total 25.850ms

07-26 19:27:58.187 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.910ms

07-26 19:27:58.204 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 50(1520B) AllocSpace objects, 45(5MB) LOS objects, 38% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 13.971ms total 47.577ms

07-26 19:27:58.398 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 166(5KB) AllocSpace objects, 162(20MB) LOS objects, 32% free, 8MB/12MB, paused 6.648ms total 31.259ms

07-26 19:27:58.715 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.558ms

07-26 19:27:58.729 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 75(2336B) AllocSpace objects, 71(9MB) LOS objects, 38% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 11.688ms total 32.283ms

07-26 19:27:59.204 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 36(1072B) AllocSpace objects, 35(4MB) LOS objects, 33% free, 7MB/11MB, paused 9.544ms total 34.012ms

07-26 19:27:59.306 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 84(2728B) AllocSpace objects, 81(10MB) LOS objects, 16% free, 6MB/7MB, paused 6.139ms total 32.936ms

07-26 19:28:01.177 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.705ms

07-26 19:28:01.187 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 154(4KB) AllocSpace objects, 148(19MB) LOS objects, 40% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 12.887ms total 42.995ms

07-26 19:28:01.676 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 80(2592B) AllocSpace objects, 75(10MB) LOS objects, 41% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 6.295ms total 24.029ms

07-26 19:28:03.325 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 36(1160B) AllocSpace objects, 34(4MB) LOS objects, 32% free, 7MB/10MB, paused 5.044ms total 27.735ms

07-26 19:28:03.682 10637-10648/com.personal.guessthecelebrity W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.750ms
```